# Accessing RouteData in Blazor Client Side AuthorizationHandler

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I am currently learning about Blazor Client Side (WebAssembly) and while looking at Authorization I was trying to validate that a user has access to a path in the URI.

Given a URI like http://localhost:1234/{route}/resource

On a page I can map route to a property but how can I get access to this value within an AuthorizationHandler to validate that the JWT has a claim with this value?

I have tried to inject RouteData and I have tried to access the HttpContext via IHttpContextAccessor but that is null.

This is the class I am trying to get working

```
public class RouteDataAccessor : IRouteDataAccessor
{
    private readonly RouteData _routeData;
    public RouteDataAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        httpContextAccessor.NullCheck(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
        httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.NullCheck(nameof(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext));

        _routeData = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData();
    }

    public bool TryGetData(string key, out string value)
    {
        value = null;
        if (_routeData == null || !_routeData.Values.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can't use HttpContext in WebAssembly Blazor app or Server Blazor app.
The following link to my answer will teach you how
[pass a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60289289/6152891) to your AuthorizationHandler. Additionally it illustrate the use of the AuthorizeView component to secure your content, and allow access to authorized users only.

Then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60284148/6152891) to get some idea how you can save your Jwt token on the local storage, how to retrieve it, and how to use it to perform HTTP calls.

Note: What is missing here a way to extract a claim from your Jwt token and pass it to your AuthorizationHandler. This merits a new question...

You also need to implement the StateAuthenticationProvider which may be combined with the Jwt token mechanism which is shown in my answer ( I call it TokenProvider)

From what you describe in your question I get the impression that every thing is new to you, so I'd suggest you [start here...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for the response, I already have the code to store the JWT in local storage and extract the claims.  Your first link has pointed me in a direction but it's a shame that I can't use an Authorize attribute on the page and just inject the RouteData into a service to handle the request.  That would have been a cleaner method that would fit with using the same code both server side and client side.